# Drawing background color between limit lines

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

Im trying to draw colors between limit lines in a LineChart, by extending the LineChart class and overriding the onDraw method. Im doing it as seen in https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/485 where colored rectangles are simply drawn on the canvas:

```
public class CustomLineChart extends LineChart {

protected Paint mYAxisZonePaint;
protected  String[] arrayColors = {"#FFFFFF","#F4D03F","#F5B041","#EB984E","#DC7633"};

    @Override
protected void init() {
    super.init();
    mYAxisZonePaint = new Paint();
    mYAxisZonePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    List<LimitLine> limitLines = mAxisLeft.getLimitLines();

    if (limitLines == null || limitLines.size() < 4){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        return;
    }

    float[] pts = new float[2];

    float startPts = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < limitLines.size(); i++) {
        pts[0] = limitLines.get(i).getLimit();
        pts[1] = startPts;

        mLeftAxisTransformer.pointValuesToPixel(pts);
        mYAxisZonePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(arrayColors[i]));

        canvas.drawRect(mViewPortHandler.contentLeft(), pts[1], mViewPortHandler.contentRight(), pts[0], mYAxisZonePaint);

        startPts = limitLines.get(i).getLimit();

    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

With the code above im able to draw the colored rectangles as a background behind the data on the line chart as seen here

[image: chart 1]

However when I scroll on the Y-axis, the rectangles will "overflow" into the area where X-axis labels are drawn as demonstrated in this image

[image: chart2]

How should i draw the colored background so it doesn't color the area where X-axis labels are drawn, similar to how the line data and limit lines are cut off just above the X-axis?

Comment: hi, can you share this graph source code? I want y-axis like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like i have found a solution to my issue. Inside the onDraw method i should restrict the area that the following draw operations can write to. I added the following to my onDraw method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    List<LimitLine> limitLines = mAxisLeft.getLimitLines();

    // Saves current canvas
    int clipRestoreCount = canvas.save();
    // Makes sure that the colored background cannot be drawn outside the content-rect. Otherwise the colored background would be drawn above and beneath the graph "borders".
    canvas.clipRect(mViewPortHandler.getContentRect());

    if (limitLines == null || limitLines.size() < 4){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        return;
    }

    float[] pts = new float[2];

    float startPts = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < limitLines.size(); i++) {
        pts[0] = limitLines.get(i).getLimit();
        pts[1] = startPts;

        mLeftAxisTransformer.pointValuesToPixel(pts);
        mYAxisZonePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(arrayColors[i]));

        canvas.drawRect(mViewPortHandler.contentLeft(), pts[1], mViewPortHandler.contentRight(), pts[0], mYAxisZonePaint);

        startPts = limitLines.get(i).getLimit();

    }

    // Removes the clipping rectangles so rest of graph elements can be drawn (like x-axis/y-axis labels)
    canvas.restoreToCount(clipRestoreCount);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyJnX.png)